# RegEx: Capturing all individual instances of a repeating capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that could be formatted in the following ways:

```
user-style-1
user-style-1-bold
user-style-1-italic
user-style-1-bold-italic
```

I'm attempting to capture (respectively):

```
nothing (does not match)
-bold
-italic
-bold and -italic (as separate captures)
```

This is my RegEx: `^user-style-\d+((-.+?)+?)$` (also potentially `^user-style-\d+(?:(-.+?)+?)$` since I don't care about the full capture, only the individual pieces of it). It captures:

```
nothing
-bold
-italic
-bold-italic and -italic
```

or (for the alternate)

```
nothing
-bold
-italic
-italic
```

I can't quite figure out how to get the repeating capture group to capture all individual instances rather than the entire thing and just the last instance or just the last instance.

Comment: Ah that does, in that it’s not possible to do what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at something like this:

```
^user-style-\d+(-\w+)(-\w+)?$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YiQkCQ/1)

You will need a group per pattern that you want to capture. Refer to link posted by `ggorlen` and the accepted answer for that question for the reasoning.

Comment: Just read that, unfortunately I was trying to have it be dynamic, guess I’ll need an alternate solution.

Comment: Just capture the tail after `user-style-\d+` and match a second time with that.

Comment: `[...s.matchAll(/^user-style-\d+(\-[\w-]+)$/gm)].map(e => e.pop().match(/-\w+/g))`

Comment: @ggorlen that's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx: `^user-style-1(-bold)?(-italic)?$`
it should capture all 4 cases

link: https://regex101.com/r/p8NbIv/1